# Does Rust have an equivalent to C's `typedef int32_t fe[10]`?

Tags: rust

Does Rust have the following type definition?

```c
typedef int32_t fe[10];
typedef struct {
    fe X;
    fe Y;
    fe Z;
    fe T;
} ge_p3;
```

I know how to define `ge_p3` in Rust, but I don't know how to define `fe`:

```
type ge_p3 {
    X:fe, Y:fe, Z: fe, T: fe
}
```

Comment: *"I know how to define ge_p3 in Rust"* that's not rust code! Also idiomatic rust code uses *snake_case* for variable names, e.g. `x`, `y`, `z`, `t` and UpperCamelCase for structs, e.g. `GeP3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=86f45bbd0fa1f0ed9a40d75f363678c8):

```
fn main() {
    let a: Int32Array = [1; 10];
    println!("{:?}", a);
    let g: GeP3 = GeP3 {
        x: a,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    println!("{:?}", g);
}
type Int32Array = [i32; 10];

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct GeP3 {
    x: Int32Array,
    y: Int32Array,
    z: Int32Array,
    t: Int32Array,
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
GeP3 { x: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], y: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], z: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], t: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }
```